# display selected options in multi select dropdown list using ajax and codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I need to display selected options (already saved options from db) in multi select dropdown list using ajax.

The response from ajax is like this

```
{"skill":[{"skill":"css"},{"skill":"Laravel"}]}
```

I need to display these values as selected in dropdown list.

my javascript ajax function

```
$.ajax({
            url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>recruiter/fetch_user_skill",
            method: "POST",
            data: {userid: user_id},
            success: function (response) {

                var JSONObject = JSON.parse(response);
                alert(response);
            }
        });
```

php script

model

```
function fetch_users_skill($user)
{
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT `skill` FROM `user_skills` WHERE user_id='$user'");

    if($query->num_rows()>0) {
        foreach($query ->result() as $row)
        {
            $data[] = $row;
        }
        return $data;
    }
}
```

controller

```
public function fetch_user_skill()
{
    $user_id = $_POST['userid'];
    $this->load->model('recruiter_model');
    $data["skill"] = $this->recruiter_model->fetch_users_skill($user_id);
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

view

```
<select class="form-control" id="skill" name="skills[]" multiple="multiple" name="skills" style="width: 600px !important;">
                    <option value="">--Select Name---</option>
                    <?php
                    if ($skills->num_rows() > 0) {
                        foreach ($skills->result() as $skills_row) {
                            ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $skills_row->skill; ?>"><?php echo $skills_row->skill; ?></option>
                            <?php
                        }
                    }
                    ?>

                </select>
```

How can I set these values as selected from js.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. You should use prepared statements.

Comment: @Dharman I think codeigniter automatically prevents sql injection by sanitising input

Comment: You don't use codeigniter. You use mysqli, and you insert the input into the SQL directly which makes it vulnerable.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>recruiter/fetch_user_skill",
        method: "POST",
        data: {userid: user_id},
        success: function (response) {

            var JSONObject = JSON.parse(response);
            Array.prototype.forEach.call(JSONObject.skill, function(v){
                $('#skill option[value=' + v.skill + ']').attr('selected', 'selected');
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you. When I click on the select box, list of options shows and the selected options highlighted. But I need to display selected options on loading the control without clicking it. is there anyway?

Comment: you can put the code inside `$(document).ready(function(){ //code goes here.. })`

Comment: Thats not possible, because the select box comes on a modal window from a button click. on that button click userid passes to the script and fetch skills of that user and populates it into the dropbox

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>recruiter/fetch_user_skill",
        method: "POST",
        data: {userid: user_id},
        success: function (response) {

            var JSONObject = JSON.parse(response);

            JsonObject.skill.forEach(function(sk){
                 $('#skill option[value=' + sk.skill + ']')
                      .prop('selected', true);
            })
        }
    });
```